# How to get data from previous step in Drupal commerce checkout process

Tags: commerce

I have Drupal commerce checkout process where user choose shipping and in next step choose payment method.

I need data about chosen shipping in payment method form alter.

Is there any way how can i get info about chosen shipping in payment method form alter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution.

```
global $user;
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$line_items_ids = array();

// get all line items IDs
foreach($order->commerce_line_items as $line_item){
  $line_items_ids[] = $line_item["line_item_id"];
}

// load only "shipping" line items
$shipping_line_items = commerce_line_item_load_multiple(
  $line_items_ids,
  array('type' => 'shipping'),
  FALSE
);
```

I haven't found cleaner way how to do this. Hope it helps somebody. I still would be glad if anyone knows how to do this better.

Comment: This is more or less what you need to do; however, a good feature request for the Shipping module would be to add an API function to make this easier.